# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Error: 102 : Role environment . FAILED TO INITIALIZE

Tags: https, azure

I am getting the following error while debugging a azure project:
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Error: 102 : Role environment . FAILED TO INITIALIZE

Using IIS7 Express.

Output windows results:

> 'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\windows\assembly\GAC_32\msshrtmi\1.6.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\msshrtmi.dll'
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Error: 102 : Role environment . FAILED TO INITIALIZE

Here is this code that fails:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(outURL, true);
```

This is going from http to https.

Answer (score 5):

I figured this out. It was simple, but the Azure project has to start first in order for the compute emulator to run. Right clicked Azure project top node and clicked debug/new instance.